# Given that $\left\{\phi, \left\{a\right\}\right\}$ , What is the power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that $\left\{\phi, \left\{a\right\}\right\}$

Is this the power set of $\mathcal{p}(a)$ or $\mathcal{p}(\left\{a\right\})$?

I initially thought it was $\mathcal{p}(a)$ but this youtube video I was learning from said it was the latter. Why is that?

Comment: This would only be $p(a)$ if $\{a\}\subset a$. Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The powerset of a set $S$ is the set of all subsets of $S$.

Even if $a$ is a set (and it may well not be), $\{ a \}$ is not a subset of $a$.

On the other hand, $\{ a \}$ is definitely a set, and so we can consider its powerset. And what are the subsets of $\{ a\}$? They are $\emptyset $ and the set $\{ a \}$ itself, hence

$$p(\{ a\})= \{ \emptyset, \{ a \} \}$$

Comment: $a$ *could* be a set however, but it is impossible for $\{a\}$ to be a subset of $a$ as per the axiom of regularity.  This directly implies what we want.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh, good point! I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Because $a$ is an element of the set $\{a\}$, not the set itself. $\emptyset$ and $\{a\}$ are subsets of $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is the we have no knowledge about the internal structure of $a$. $a$ is just a variable standing in for a set, so if you substitute any set you are familiar with for $a$, you should expect to get a different power set. Therefore, we can't talk about $P(a)$.

$\{a\}$, only the other hand, is easy to talk about. It is a set with just one element, called "$a$". Like any other set with one element, $P(\{a\})$ has $2^1 = 2$ elements: the two elements mentioned in your answer. The only subsets are the empty set and the subset that contains that single element.